# What does "chicken in a pot" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Sweet Smell of Success* (1957), Sidney planted a smear
on Dallas, who is having a affair with Susan whose brother is J.J:

> Sidney: Auntie Van Cleve is firing him. I just got it from the horse's
> mouth. They were just here in a panic.
>
> J.J: You mean to say they've already traced the smear to you? Then
> what are you so smug about? Susie isn't dumb. All she does is put two
> and two together, and I'm a **chicken in a pot**.

What does "chicken in a pot" mean?

Comment: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/chicken-in-a-pot.3385303/

Comment: I'm trapped in a bad situation, like a chicken which is being cooked.

Comment: @Esther Other forums posts are valid here?

Comment: A similar phrase sometimes used is "... I am [dead meat](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dead+meat)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We often use expressions comparing a person in trouble to an animal being killed or cooked, or something being cooked.

> If my father hears I dented his car, I'm toast!

> If my boss finds my mistake, I'll be roasted alive!

A chicken in a pot is, in a way, trebly unlucky, because it is (1) dead, (2) being cooked, and (3) confined in a pot, with no possibility of escape. Saying he **will be** a 'chicken in a pot' combines all these into a figure of speech called a 'metaphor'. If he said 'I **will be like** a chicken in a pot', he would be using another type of figure of speech, called a 'simile'.

[Metaphor (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/metaphor)

[Simile (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/simile)